# Is this a bug of typescript language?

Tags: typescript

Please take a look at the code snippet below, the last line demonstrate a bug. How should I report it ?

```
interface Type1 {
    optionalA?: {
        rendered: string;
        text?: string;
    };
}
type MyType = Type1["optionalA"];

const x: MyType = { rendered: "on" };
const y: Omit<MyType, "text"> = { rendered: "on" };
const w: MyType & { text?: string } = { rendered: "on" };
// this line fail with error Object literal may only specify known properties, and rendered does not exist in type ...
// while it shouldn't, this seems to be a bug caused by the combination of referencing a type by an optional member("optionalA") of
// another type, Omit and & operator, the problem seems to be the resolved object type looses all its members
const z: Omit<MyType, "text"> & { text?: string } = { rendered: "on" };
```

Create a .ts with the above snippet, compiler gives error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'rendered' does not exist in type 'Omit<{ rendered: string; text?: string | undefined; } | undefined, "text"> & { text?: string | undefined; }'.

Expected result: no error is given.

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in TypeScript, you can file a bug report here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Too much is going on in this example; could you please [edit] to reduce it to a [mre]?  `Type1` doesn't need to be presented if you only access it as `MyType` (just define `MyType` directly) `Omit<MyType, "text">` is just `{}`. If you mean `{}`, then write that.  If not, then you should fix it to be what you do mean.

Comment: @jcalz Why does `Omit<MyType, "text">` result in `{}` instead of `{rendered: string} | undefined`? It's true (just checked in VSCode), but it makes no sense to me. Edit: And will your answer be short enough to fit in another comment, or is this worth creating a separate question?

Comment: Since the property `optionalA?` is optional it can be undefined. `MyType = { rendered: string; text?: string | undefined; } | undefined`.  `Omit<MyType, "text">` is actually `{}` since `MyType` can be `undefined` (lowest type) hence `Omit<MyType, "text"> & { text?: string }` results in `{ text?: string }`.

Comment: `Omit` isn't distributive over unions (see [ms/TS#31501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31501)) so you tend to only see keys present on every member in the union; `undefined` has no keys, so that's what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a typescript bug. It is an expected behavior of your type `MyType` in combination with `Omit`. When you have a look into your interface `Type1` you defined the property `optionalA` as optional. This means `optionalA` could be of type `undefined` or your defined type.
And so `MyType` is a union type of `optionalA` and `undefined`.

How does Utility Type Omit work?

Omit will create a mathematically intersection of all types of the union type `MyType`.
More precisely because of Omit is using the utility type Pick under the hood. Pick defines a `K extends keyof T` constraint and `keyof` for unions will just return the keys, which are in all types of your union type `MyType`.

Utils Type definitions:

```
// T would be your union type MyType
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

// keyof T(MyType) creates an union without keys
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

The result of `Omit<MyType, "text">` is an empty object, because of `optionalA` and `undefined` have no intersections. Thats the reason why you cannot declare an object with the property `rendered`, because this property is not anymore in your type definition.

```
interface Type1 {
    optionalA?: {
        rendered: string;
        text?: string;
    };
}

type MyType = Type1["optionalA"]; 
// MyType = { rendered: string; text?: string; } | undefined 

type OmitMyType = Omit<MyType, "text">
// { rendered: string; text?: string; } intersection with undefined results in "{}"

const z: OmitMyType & { text?: string } = { rendered: "on" }; 
// {} & { text?: string } does not match with {rendered: string}
```

Here are two solutions to get your code running:

```
interface Type1 {
    optionalA: { // make optionalA required 
        rendered: string;
        text?: string;
    };
}

OR

type MyType = NonNullable<MyType["optionalA"]> 
// NonNullable removes null and undefined from type
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and suggested solutions. The solution of adding NonNullable works for me.

Comment: Also, the reason I was confused and thought it was a typescript bug because I thought Omit<MyType, text> must be { rendered: string } because it matches { rendered: "on" }, I didn't know that empty object also matches it.